# How can I find the encoding of a mail message?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, pop3

I'm downloading a message from gmail using pop3.

When the message is in ansi every thing is OK but when there is another language I get gibberish

Any ideas?

Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the message content is encoded using BASE64 or Quoted-Printable.

You need to check Content-Transfer-Encoding header.
You can use Convert.FromBase64String(string s) method to decode BASE64.

...or you can use a commercial component as MIME is tricky.